# spliting the html files using perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl but I have tried to write a program to split a single HTML file into multiple HTML files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
#use warnings;

my @file_names;

## Read the list of file names
open( my $fh, "$ARGV[0]" );
while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;    #remove new line character from the end of the line
    push @file_names, $_;
}

my $counter = 0;
my ( $file_name, $fn );

## Read the input file
open( $fh, "$ARGV[1]" );
while ( <$fh> ) {

    ## If this is an opening class, open the next output file,
    ## and set $counter to 1.

    if ( / class="bch_ha"/ ) {
        $counter   = 1;
        $file_name = shift(@file_names);
        open( $fn, ">", "$file_name" );

        #print "<html>\n<body>";
    }

    ## If this is a closing class, print the line and set $counter back to 0

    if ( /\n<p sourcepage="(\d+)" class="bch_ha"/ ) {
        $counter = 0;
        print $fn $_;
        close($fn);
    }

    if ( / class="bcesu_tt"/ ) {
        $counter   = 1;
        $file_name = shift(@file_names);
        open( $fn, ">", "$file_name" );

        #print "<html>\n<body>";
    }

    if ( /\n<p sourcepage="(\d+)" class="bcekt_tt"/ ) {
        $counter = 0;
        print $fn $_;
        close($fn);
    }

    if (/ class="bcekt_tt"/ ) {
        $counter   = 1;
        $file_name = shift(@file_names);
        open( $fn, ">", "$file_name" );

        #print "<html>\n<body>";
    }

    if ( /\n<p sourcepage="(\d+)" class="bcepq_tt"/ ) {
        $counter = 0;
        print $fn $_;
        close($fn);
    }

    if ( / class="bcepq_tt"/ ) {
        $counter   = 1;
        $file_name = shift(@file_names);
        open( $fn, ">", "$file_name" );

        #print "<html>\n<body>";
    }

    if ( /\n<p sourcepage="(\d+)" class="bcecs_tt"/ ) {
        $counter = 0;
        print $fn $_;
        close($fn);
    }

    if ( / class="bcecs_tt"/ ) {
        $counter   = 1;
        $file_name = shift(@file_names);
        open( $fn, ">", "$file_name" );

        #print "<html>\n<body>";
    }

    if ( /\n<p sourcepage="(\d+)" class="bceex_tt"/ ) {
        $counter = 0;
        print $fn $_;
        close($fn);
    }

    if ( / class="bceex_tt"/ ) {
        $counter   = 1;
        $file_name = shift(@file_names);
        open( $fn, ">", "$file_name" );

        #print "<html>\n<body>";
    }

    if ( /\n<\/body>\n<\/html>/ ) {
        $counter = 0;
        print $fn $_;
        close($fn);
    }

    ## Print into the corresponding file handle if $counter is 1

    print $fn $_ if $counter == 1
}
```

I need to add some more options. The code should ask for manual input for the delimiters and the split files should go to folder name `chapterxx`. Please help me on this

Yeah Please find the below HTML sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p sourcepage="27" `class="bch_ha"`></p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_ct">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_cr">Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%    <i>Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</i></p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bch_nmword">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bch_nm">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bch_tt">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_tt">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%    <b>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%    </b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</i></p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lbfirst">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lb">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lb">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lb">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
<p sourcepage="26" class="bch_ha">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_lblast">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b>    </p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bopcs_txfirst">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
<p sourcepage="26"     class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
<p sourcepage="27" class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
<p sourcepage="27" class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%<span class="sup">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</sup>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
<p sourcepage="27" class="bch_txfirst">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I just need to split the html based on the class `class="bch_ha"` to next `class="bch_ha"` and write the content in new html named reader_0.html. the file name will be incremental like reader_1.html.

Comment: You mustn't comment out `use warnings`. The messages are there to indicate that something's not quite right in your code, and switching them off doesn't fix the problem!

Comment: This should be done with a proper HTML parser. Please show the original HTML so that we can help you properly. If it's on line then a link is fine

Comment: The HTML i cannot share because of its confidential official things. I just need to split the html file in to multiple files by using the class name, which u can see above in my coding. but that should be in dynamic and i need to  create a directory with the name of input file and the all splitted html's need to move inside the folder.

Comment: Then please show an equivalent HTML file with the sensitive text altered. It is really very difficult to help you without it

Comment: I have added above the sample code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will give you an idea on how to be able to complete your program.

In this example the focus is on how to split files based on the delimiter.

Note: Only the html body is saved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = './htmlInput.html'; # input file
my $delim = 'class="bch_ha"'; # delimiter
my $dir = 'chapter' . time; # folder with unix timestamp

# mkdir returns 1 if success
if ( mkdir($dir, 0755) ) {
    print "INFO: Created folder $dir to collect files.\n";  
} else {
    die "Can't make folder $dir\n";
}

# reader_x.html, x = [0..]
my $reader = 'reader_0.html';

my $fh2;
my $cnt = 0;
my $delim_first_time = 1;
open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open and read $file: $!"; # read file
while (my $li = <$fh>) {
    last if ( $li =~ /<\/body>/ ); # quit the while loop

    if ( $delim_first_time && $li =~ /$delim/ ) { 
        open($fh2, ">", "./$dir/$reader") or die "Can't write to $reader : $!"; # write
        $delim_first_time = 0;
    } elsif ( $li =~ /$delim/ ) {
        close($fh2);
        $cnt++;
        $reader =~ s/[0-9]+/$cnt/; # reader_0.html -> reader_1.html
        open($fh2, ">", "./$dir/$reader") or die "Can't write to $reader : $!"; # write
    }
    print $fh2 $li if !$delim_first_time;
}
close($fh);
close($fh2);

# output:
# [~]$ ./test.pl
# INFO: Created folder chapter1465642603 to collect files.
# [~]$ ls chapter1465642603
# reader_0.html  reader_1.html
# [~]$ cat chapter1465642603/reader_0.html
# <p sourcepage="27" `class="bch_ha"`></p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_ct">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_cr">Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%    <i>Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</i></p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bch_nmword">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bch_nm">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bch_tt">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_tt">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%    <b>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%    </b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</i></p>
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lbfirst">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lb">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lb">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bopob_lb">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
# [~]$
# [~]$ cat chapter1465642603/reader_1.html
# <p sourcepage="26" class="bch_ha">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b></p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bopob_lblast">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</b>    </p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bopcs_txfirst">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# <p sourcepage="26"     class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# <p sourcepage="27" class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# <p sourcepage="27" class="bopcs_tx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%<span class="sup">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</sup>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# <p sourcepage="27" class="bch_txfirst">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%</p>
# [~]$
```